# Responsive carousel

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

How do I make the section of my carousel constant when I have different sized items in it and put the carousel in the center (Horizontally AND vertically).

[image: Screenshot of code.]

Comment: In place of screenshot, please add the code snippet, this will help us to understand the problem more

Comment: Please see [ask], and the SO [tour].